# Ambiguous column name 'Doc_Date'

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT  CH.Net_Amount AS Net_Amount,
        GD.Guest_Name AS Customer_Name,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CH.Doc_Date,(120)) AS Doc_Date,
        LGH.Node_Name AS Location_Name, 
        [booking].[Calculate_Room_Charge] (CH.Booking_Code ) AS Roomcharge,
        (CH.Net_Amount-[booking].[Calculate_Room_Charge] (CH.Booking_Code ) )AS ServiceCharge
FROM [booking].[Checkout_Header] AS CH  
LEFT JOIN [booking].[Booking_Header] AS BH 
    ON CH.Booking_Code=BH.Doc_No
LEFT JOIN [booking].[Booking_Details]AS BD 
    ON BH.Doc_No=BD.Doc_No
LEFT JOIN [booking].[Guest_Details] AS GD 
    ON BD.Customer_Code=GD.Guest_Code
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[User_Locations] AS UL 
    ON  CH.Setup_Location_Code = UL.Location_Code
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Location_Group_Header] AS LGH 
    ON LGH.Node_Code = UL.Location_Code
WHERE UL.User_Code= 'EZCMP1/EZUSR-8' AND UL.Status = 0 AND CH.Status=0  AND CH.Checkout_Status=1 
GROUP BY Doc_Date,LGH.Node_Name,GD.Guest_Name,CH.Net_Amount 
ORDER BY Doc_Date
```

The above query returns:

> 'Doc_Date' is Ambiguous

I gave alias correctly as I think. So why still doc date is ambiguous?

Answer (score 2):

Change GROUP BY and ORDER BY to this:

```
GROUP BY CH.Doc_Date,LGH.Node_Name,GD.Guest_Name,CH.Net_Amount 
ORDER BY CH.Doc_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
GROUP BY CH.Doc_Date,LGH.Node_Name,GD.Guest_Name,CH.Net_Amount 
ORDER BY CH.Doc_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `Doc_Date`, it is in multiple tables. While grouping it can't identify which table of `Doc_Date` you want to group by. To distinguish `Doc_Date` for group by you have to give the doc_date field an `alias`. And group by
like this;

```
GROUP BY [aliasname].Doc_Date,LGH.Node_Name,GD.Guest_Name,CH.Net_Amount 
ORDER BY [aliasname].Doc_Date
```